# Search for value in column B, replace column D & E of that row

Tags: vba

New to VBA so go easy on me.

I have a spreadsheet in the below format:

[image]

I require VBA that will search column B for the term "LBR-0001", then replace the contents of column D in that row with the value "25", and column E in that row with "AUD". The row containing "LBR-0001" will change so this cannot be hard coded to a particular row.

Currently I am using the code below but it is far too slow to complete since it searches up to 10,000 rows.

```
For i = 1 To 10000
    With Sheets("LPP_Previous_Month")
    If .Range("B" & i).Value = "LBR-0001" Then _
    .Range("D" & i).Value = "25"
    .Range("E" & i).Value = "AUD"
    End With
Next i
```

Any improvements would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the worksheet's Match function to quickly locate a matching row in column B. Use that row number to set the values in columns D and E.

```
dim m as variant

With Sheets("LPP_Previous_Month")

    m = application.match("LBR-0001", .range("B:B"), 0)

    if not iserror(m) then
        .cells(m, "D") = 25
        .cells(m, "E") = "AUD"
    end if

End With
```

Use Application.Match (not worksheetfunction.match) and return the result to a variant. This is the only way to reliably test using IsError.

Comment: Lifesaver. That works perfectly, thank you very much.